How to update includePath without using quick fix?
I'm using the C extension for vs code and have this error. All the tutorials online led to clicking "Quick Fix" followed by "Edit includePath settings", but there is no such option in my Quick Fixes. Is there any other way to update this?



Welcome to SO. This setting is stored in c_cpp_properties.json. Does this manual help? c_cpp_properties.json reference

Press the Ctrl+shift+p key, input >c++edit configurations JSON, press enter, and write your header file path in includePath
For example:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include" // Your header directory
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "D:\\ProgramFiles\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

